# datatable en SweetAlert2

Tags: jquery, datatables

Estoy cargando un datatable a un sweetalert2, en el cual quiero mostrar la lista de alumnos que estan registrados en esa clase, de lo contrario hacer otra cosa, el problema es que no me carga los datos.

con ese código me carga los datos, pero me da un error en consola que me dice que reload no es una funcion, intente con ajax.reload(); pero me lanza error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable(...).reload is not a function`

```
"initComplete": function(settings, json) {
  $("#alumnosCurso").DataTable().reload();
},
```

Este es la funcion completa en que ejecuto el sweetalert2 con el datatable

```
$('body').on('click', '.eliminarCurso', function () { // Boton eliminar Datatable
  var id_curso = $(this).data("id");

  var view_html='';
  var url = "{{ url('getAlumnosCurso') }}/"+id_curso;

  $.get(url, function (r) { // hago la consula a mi tabla alumnos
    var data = $.parseJSON(r);
    console.log(data);
    if(data==null){ // si no hay alumnos registrados con este curso

    }else{ // si existe hago lo siguiente
      $.each(data, function(i) {

        var alumnosCurso = '<table id="alumnosCurso" class="table table-striped nowrap" width="100%"><thead><tr><th>Rut</th><th>Nombre</th><th>Apellidos</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table>';

        $('#alumnosCurso').DataTable({
          'paging'      : false,
          'lengthChange': false,
          'searching'   : false,
          'ordering'    : false,
          'processing'  : false,
          'info'        : false,
          'autoWidth'   : true,
          'responsive'  : true, 
          'data'        : data,
          'columns': [
            { data: 'rut'},
            { data: 'nombre'},
            { data: 'apellidos'}
          ]
        });

        Swal.fire({
          title: 'CUIDADO!',
          text: 'ZY',
          html: alumnosCurso,
          type: 'warning',
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
          cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
          confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
        }).then((result) => {
          if (result.value) {
            Swal.fire(
              'Deleted!',
              'Your file has been deleted.',
              'success'
            )
          }
        })
      })
    }
  });
});
```

el formato del data es el siguiente 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

adjunto esta imagen en la cual se ve lo que quiero hacer, pero me da ese error en consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUCIONADO**

opte por cargar la datatable por ajax, pero este me daba un problema al cargar la datatable, ya que como lo mostraba en la pregunta, cargaba primero el sweetalert antes que la datatable, asi que lo que hice fue colocar el sweetalert dentro del *initComplete* el cual su funcion es ejecutar "algo" despues de que la tabla este cargada

aqui la solucion

**DataTable**

```
<div hidden>
  <table id="alumnosCurso" class="table table-striped nowrap" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Rut</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellidos</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Funcion de btn *eliminar**

El sweetalert dentro del *initComplete*

```
$('body').on('click', '.eliminarCurso', function () { // Boton eliminar Datatable
  $('#alumnosCurso').DataTable().destroy();
  var id_curso = $(this).data("id");

  var view_html='';
  var url = "{{ url('getAlumnosCurso') }}/"+id_curso;

  $.get(url, function (r) { // hago la consula a mi tabla alumnos
    var data = $.parseJSON(r);
      if(data==null){ // si no hay alumnos registrados con este curso
        swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire({
          title: 'Estas seguro?',
          text: "El curso sera eliminado junto a las clases asignadas a este",
          type: 'warning',
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
          cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
          confirmButtonText: 'Si, eliminar',
          cancelButtonText: 'No, cancelar'
        }).then((result) => {
          if (result.value) {
            $.ajax({
              type: "DELETE",
              url: "{{ route('curso.store') }}"+'/'+id_curso,
              success: function (data) {
                Toast.fire({
                  type: 'success',
                  title: 'El curso ha sido eliminado con éxito!'
                })
                table.draw();
              },
              error: function (data) {
                Toast.fire({
                  type: 'error',
                  title: 'Ocurrio un problema'
                })
                console.log('Error:', data);
              }
            });
          }
        })
      }else{ // si existe hago lo siguiente
        var rut = "rut";
        var nombre = "nombre";
        var apellidos = "apellidos";
        $('#alumnosCurso').DataTable({
          'paging'      : false,
          'lengthChange': true,
          'searching'   : false,
          'ordering'    : false,
          'processing'  : true,
          'info'        : true,
          'autoWidth'   : true,
          'language'    : lenguaje_es,
          'responsive'  : true,
          'serverSide'  : true,
          "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
            var dt = $('#alumnosCurso');
            Swal.fire({
              title: 'El curso no puede ser eliminado,'+'<br>'+'tiene alumnos asignados!',
              html: dt,
              type: 'error',
              showCancelButton: false,
              confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
              confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar'
            })
          },
          'ajax'        : {
            'url': "{{ route('curso.ver_alumnos_curso') }}",
            'data': {"id_curso": id_curso},
            'type': "POST"
          },
          'columns': [
            { data: rut},
            { data: nombre},
            { data: apellidos}
          ]
        });
        $("#alumnosCurso").DataTable().ajax.reload();
      }
  })
});
```

**Ruta**

```
Route::post('ver_alumnos_curso','cursoController@ver_alumnos_curso')->name('curso.ver_alumnos_curso');
```

**Función de la ruta en el *controller***

```
public function ver_alumnos_curso(Request $request){ 
  if ($request->ajax()) {
    $id_curso = $request->get('id_curso');
    $alumnos = alumnoModel::latest()->where('id_curso','=',$id_curso)->get();
    return datatables::of($alumnos)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->make(true);
  }
  return view('curso.curso');
}
```

y este es el resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]